# Can't Stop a Gear Rotation

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, event-handling

i am newbie in AS3 programming. I want to ask how to stop this gear animation. I just make a function to stop the rotation but the event is not going to stop.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var smallGearSpeed:Number = -2;
var bigGearSpeed:Number = 1;

btn_Normal.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_rotateNormalHandler);
btn_Acc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_rotateAccHandler);
btn_Stop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_rotateStopHandler);

function fl_rotateStopHandler (evt:MouseEvent):void {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_rotateStop);
    }

function fl_rotateNormalHandler (evt:MouseEvent):void {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_rotateNormal);
    }

function fl_rotateAccHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_rotateAcc);
    }


function fl_rotateNormal (evt:Event):void {
        rotateNormal();

    }

function fl_rotateAcc (evt:Event):void {
        rotateAcc();

    }

function fl_rotateStop (evt:Event):void {
        rotateStop();

    }

function rotateNormal():void {
        mc_BigGear.rotation += bigGearSpeed;
        mc_SmallGear.rotation += smallGearSpeed;

        trace("Normal Clicked !!!");

    }

function rotateAcc():void {
        mc_BigGear.rotation += bigGearSpeed;
        bigGearSpeed = bigGearSpeed + .1;

        mc_SmallGear.rotation += smallGearSpeed;
        smallGearSpeed = smallGearSpeed - .1;

        trace("Accelerate Clicked !!!");

    }

function rotateStop():void {
        mc_BigGear.rotation = bigGearSpeed - 1;
        mc_SmallGear.rotation = smallGearSpeed + 2;

        trace("Stop Clicked !!!");

    }
```

I hope someone can help me solve this problem. Sorry for my bad English , Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "stop" the event, remove the listener that you previously added, something like:

```
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_rotateNormal);
```

Comment: thank you very much for solving my problem , its worked !! :)